# Why can you access and manipulate private Members of your own class

Tags: java, access-violation

When it comes to a copy-constructor, and a lot of other cases, it makes sense, yes. But why is it allowed?

If you create a static or nonstatic Method in the class, you can manipulate the value of the variable.

```
public class CopyMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(1); //val = 1
        TestClass.manipulate(tc); //val = 5
        TestClass.foo(tc); //print out 5

        TestClass tc2 = new TestClass(tc); //tc,s val will be 6 afterwards
        TestClass.foo(tc); //print out 6
    }
}


class TestClass{
    private int val;

    public TestClass(int val){
        this.val = val;
    }

    public TestClass(TestClass t){
        this.val = t.val;
        t.val = 6;
    }

    public static void foo(TestClass tc){
        System.out.println(tc.val);
    }

    public static void manipulate(TestClass tc){
        tc.val = 5;
    }
}
```

The read and write of the value is written within the class (context?). But won't it hurt the access-restrictions I want with private? I'm not accessing the objects own value (like a getter/settter) but I do it to the object given with the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this access is allowed, is to allow you to implement methods such as `equals` and `clone` which have to access the private data members of another instance of the same class in order to do their job.

Example :

```
public Object clone ()
{
    MyClass other = new MyClass ();
    other.somePrivateMember = this.somePrivateMember;
    ...
    return other;
}
```

Comment: Hmh, that is certainly an important use case, but is it the actual reason? You'd have to give some proof to such a claim...

Answer (score 0):

Java was designed carefully (as a reaction to C++, whose worth nevertheless is high).

If you are in a class, you have those two alternatives for `private`:

1. Allow inside the class to access the private things of all instances.
2. Only allow access to this's private members.

So a decision only makes sense in a context of another instance.
Forbidding would mean that you would need `public` methods, maybe for *internal*, non-public operations.

Hence 1. was a logical choice to make: not exposing too much, not needing plumbing, And it is more efficient for the JVM and symmetric in coding.